# Changing Class for Elements as Page Changes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a document for work, and I'm wanting to use a single JavaScript document to control page links and navigation by detecting the browser URL.  I have it set up (without JS) to change a link from a hover to a background-image using CSS, but I'm having a difficult time setting it up with JS.

This is the code I have for URL detection:

```
var x = document.location.href.split("/");
var page = x[x.length-1];
```

This is the if statement I attempted to write to run a class depending on the page:

```
if (page == "orders.html"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("orders")[0].removeAttribute("linkElem")
}
```

This is what I have for setting up the navigation links:

```
var parentElem = document.getElementById("table1").parentElement.parentElement;
var linkText = "Orders";
var linkHREF = "orders.html";
var classText = "orders";
var classText1 = "orders1";
var linkElem = "<tr><td class=\"" + classText + "\" id=\"" + linkText + "\"><a href=\"" +     linkHREF +  "\">" + linkText + "</a></td></tr>";
var linkElem1 = "<tr><td class=\"" + classText1 + "\" id=\"" + linkText + "\">" + linkText + "</td></tr>";
parentElem.innerHTML += linkElem;
parentElem.innerHTML += linkElem1;
```

This is the element on the page where the navigation goes:

```
<table class="tablenav">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ordernav" id="table1">STWD Navigation</td>
    </tr>
        </table><br/>
<table class="tablenav">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ordernav" id="table2">Tracking Generation</td>
    </tr>
</table><br/>
```

When the link is hovered over:

```
.orders:hover {
  background-image:url('buttons/orders.jpg');
  width:819px
}
```

I want the hover picture to remain on the link as long as you're on the page.

Let me know what's going on and what needs to be done, or if more information is needed.

Comment: Why do you have an ID of "table1" on a cell when you want to access the table section above it? Modifying table structure using innerHTML will fail in IE, [*it's not supported*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The way I have the page set up is in four adjacent squares. The tablenav element is located in one of those squares, and I'm trying to add the navigation elements to the table1 element.

Comment: You have to modify tables using DOM methods `(var row = parentElem.insertRow(-1); var cell = row.insertCell(-1);`, etc.